# preventDefault() does not prevent SVG load on mobile devices while using slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, html, svg, slidetoggle, preventdefault

I have a navigation that uses SVG animation to show which section in the page the user is in. The navigation is opened and closed in mobile view (below 700px wide) by tapping an arrow icon and firing a `slideToggle()` method. SVGs are inline and are being loaded on page load.

The SVG that corresponds to each button is only loaded when the user is in a specific scroll position. To prevent all the SVG's from loading on each toggle I used `preventDefault()` in the toggle click event, which gave me the desired result on desktop. Only the SVG of the corresponding page section was loaded.

Unfortunately all SVG's are being loaded with each toggle event on MOBILE browsers (safari and chrome from what I've tried). I've tried doing `preventDefault()` on tap and touch events, but the loads keep happening on mobile and I can't figure out why.

```
<div id='toggle'>
  <div class='nav-circle'>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
  <div>
    <div class='nav-circle'>
      <%= link_to root_path(:anchor => "portfolio") do %>
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id='briefcase-container'></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='nav-circle'>
      <%= link_to root_path(:anchor => "school") do %>
      <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id='education-container'></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='nav-circle'>
      <%= link_to root_path(:anchor => "about") do %>
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id='user-container'></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class='nav-circle'>
      <%= link_to root_path(:anchor => "contact") do %>
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id='envelope-container'></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Load Nav Shading
  var position = $(window).scrollTop() + 170;
  var contactPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + 500;
  $('#briefcase-container').load('img/svg/briefcase.svg', function(){
    var portfolioTop = $(".portfolio-section").offset().top;
    var portfolioBottom =  portfolioTop + $(".portfolio-section").height();
    if (position >= portfolioTop && position <= portfolioBottom){
      $('.briefcase-shading').css('animation', 'draw-briefcase .5s linear forwards normal 1 running');
    }
  });
  $('#education-container').load('img/svg/education.svg', function(){
    var educationTop = $(".education-section").offset().top;
    var educationBottom =  educationTop + $(".education-section").height();
    if (position >= educationTop && position <= educationBottom){
      $('.education-shading').css('animation', 'draw-education .5s linear forwards normal 1 running');
    }
  });
  $('#envelope-container').load('img/svg/envelope.svg', function(){
    var contactTop = $(".contact-section").offset().top;
    var contactBottom =  contactTop + $(".contact-section").height();
    if (contactPosition >= contactTop && contactPosition <= contactBottom){
      $('.envelope-shading').css('animation', 'draw-envelope .5s linear forwards normal 1 running');
    }
  });
  $('#user-container').load('img/svg/user.svg', function(){
    var aboutTop = $(".about-section").offset().top;
    var aboutBottom =  aboutTop + $(".about-section").height();
    if (position >= aboutTop && position <= aboutBottom){
      $('.user-shading').css('animation', 'draw-user .5s linear forwards normal 1 running');
    }
  });

  //Nav Show-Hide
  $('#toggle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').slideToggle();
    //rotate toggle button
    $('.fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('toggleDown');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use touchstart or touchend.

Mobile doesn't have a click() function.

```
$('#toggle').bind('touchstart click', function(e){
```